# How to create a simple API with origin restriction

Tags: php, api, laravel

I have a website that handle user requests made with Laravel4 (calling it the "app"). I also have 10 websites made with different engines (Joomla / Wordpress / Laravel / Pure PHP). I want to create a simple API so when a user send a form from one of the 10 websites it's sent to my app API. The API part is realy light, it's just for receiving the post datas and save them to the DB, nothing else.

So my problem is that I don't know how to "secure" my API without having to use OAuth2 or things like that, that looks to massive for my needs. I just want a way to be sure that the calls to the API have been made by one of my websites (without being spoofable). And also crypt them...

Do you have any advices ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without rewriting an Oauth like ^^.

What you can do if you want something simple and enough secure :

1. Use HTTPS for transaction (prevent man in the middle)
2. Use a IPs white-list from your server that host your API (prevent nothing, just newbie hackers ^^)
3. Use a secret token that you use for each transaction (prevent IP spoofing)

You can increase your security... but you will closer to Oauth or any other authorization system that you have to use.